# /var/log/cups keeps increasing while the cups service is stopped

Tags: 12.04, printing, services, log

I want to stop CUPS service on my 12.04 ubuntu:

```
sudo service cups stop
```

it's stopped. I check it's status by :

```
chkconfig
```

it's **off**

but `/var/log/cups` size is still increasing by a large amount each minute.
I am running out of disk space, what can I do to stop this?

```
ls -lhS /var/log/cups/ | head 

total 1.5G
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.5G Jan 7 12:50 error_log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 8.1M Jan 7 11:14 error_log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 587 Dec 30 07:37 access_log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 259 Dec 29 07:59 aacess_log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 258 Dec 28 07:41 aacess_log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 255 Dec 27 07:23 aacess_log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 252 Dec 26 07:04 aacess_log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 245 Dec 29 14:34 error_log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 230 Dec 25 07:44 aacess_log.6.gz
```

Comment: What do you mean by alive and growing fast?

Comment: it's size is growing so fast. it fills about 1GB through 1 min!!

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what you mean. Can you describe, what you are doing and what exactly (file name or program) grows in size? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -lhS /var/log/cups/ | head`

Comment: Updated mu post

Comment: hmm, can you also post the output of `tail /var/log/cups/error_log`?